# setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) works in one part of the code, but setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) doesn't

Tags: colors, android-imageview

I was trying to have an imageView change colors programmatically, but it looked like only setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) was executing and setBackgroundColor(RED) was not.

ANSWER: The ImageView in my RelativeLayout file was being covered up by another element.

When I call happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) nothing happens. The Logcat indicates that the app has reached that line of code, but I do not get an error of any sort.

When I call happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) it works just fine.

Why is this? Even if there is a work around, I'd like to know why my code doesn't work.

Using Android Studio v 1.0.2
testing on Nexus 5.0.1

I've included the testForErrors class and the GaussAlgorithm class, but I do not think these are part of the problem.

My MainActivity is here:

```
package dayOfWeekApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

import com.example.com.piercestudio.R;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        final TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        final EditText editTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final ImageView happybirthdayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    Log.i(testForErrors.E, "Lost focus, getting it back");
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        editTextField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                    calculateButton.callOnClick();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(testForErrors.E, "CLICK");
                String mArray[] = {editTextField.getText().toString(), "error"};

                //error testing:
                mArray = testForErrors.check(mArray);

                if (mArray[1].equals("error")) {

                    Log.i(testForErrors.E, "error passed to main");
                    if(mArray[0].length() == 0){
                        //Intentionally blank so that touching the button does not give errors on pushing the button accidently.
                    }
                    else{

                        //-------
```

Here is where the imageView should turn RED

```
                        happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        Log.i(testForErrors.E, "background RED");

                        //-------

                        calculateButton.setText(mArray[0] + " is not a real date");
                        editTextField.requestFocus();
                    }


                } else {
                    Log.i(testForErrors.E, "no error passed to main");

                    if (mArray[0].startsWith("10/25")) {
                        Log.i(testForErrors.E, "Birthday entered");
                        happybirthdayimage.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happybirthday));
                        editTextField.requestFocus();
                        if(editTextField.hasFocus()) {
                            Log.i(testForErrors.E, "editText has focus");
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.i(testForErrors.E, "editText does not have focus");
                        }
                        Log.i(testForErrors.E, "background birthday");
                        editTextField.setText(null);
                        editTextField.requestFocus();
                        Log.i(testForErrors.E, "text to null");
                    } else {
```

Here is where it does turn WHITE

```
                        happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        Log.i(testForErrors.E, "background WHITE");
                    }
                }
                if (!(mArray[1].equals("error"))) {
                    Log.i(testForErrors.E, "pass to gauss");
                    resultView.setText(GuassAlgorithm.getDate(mArray[0]));

                    calculateButton.setText("I think it's " + GuassAlgorithm.getDate(mArray[0]));
                }
                editTextField.setText(null);
            }

        });


    }
}
```

XML Layout:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:background="#ffffffff"
tools:context="dayOfWeekApp.MainActivity"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/introText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome! What day was it then? Enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format and you'll see the answer below!"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/typeDateHere"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Type the date in here:"
    android:paddingBottom="40sp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/introText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/typeDateHere"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click here for the day!"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The day will show up here :)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_below="@id/calculateButton"
    />

<ImageView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_above="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resultTextView"
    />
```

Error checking class and method:

```
package dayOfWeekApp;

import android.util.Log;
public class testForErrors {

    public static String E = "TAG";


        public static String[] check(String[] sArray){
        String s = sArray[0];
        sArray[1] = "error";

    if (s == null || s.length() != 10) {
        Log.i(E, "length out of bounds or null");
        return sArray;
    }

    Log.i(E, s.substring(0,2) + s.substring(2,3) + s.substring(3,5) + s.substring(5,6) + s.substring(6));

    try {
        if((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0 && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 13)) != true) {
            Log.i(E, "month out of bounds");
            return sArray;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.i(E, "month out of bounds error");
        return sArray;
    }
        Log.i(E, "month in bounds");

    int month = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2));
        Log.i(E, "month = " + Integer.toString(month));

    //this activates only after the month has passed it's test
    //if it were inside the "try" block 1: the rest of the code couldn't see it.
    //10/25/1980

    try {
        Log.i(E, s);
        if(s.substring(2,3).equals("/") != true) {
            Log.i(E, s.substring(2,3));
            Log.i(E, "first slash out of bounds");
            return sArray;
            }
        }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Log.i(E, "first slash error");
        return sArray;
    }
    Log.i(E, "first slash in bounds");

    //day
    try {
        if((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5)) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5)) < 32) != true){
            Log.i(E, "day out of bounds");
            return sArray;
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Log.i(E, "day error");
            return sArray;
        }

    Log.i(E, "day in bounds");

    try{
        if ((month > 1 && month < 13) != true){
            Log.i(E, "month out of bounds");
            return sArray;
        }
    }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            Log.i(E, "month error");
            return sArray;
        }
    Log.i(E, "month in bounds");

        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Jan out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Jan error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Jan in bounds");
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 29) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Feb out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Feb error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Fed in bounds");
            case 3:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Mar out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Mar error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Mar in bounds");
                break;
            case 4:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 31) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Apr out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Apr error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Apr in bounds");
                break;
            case 5:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "May out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "May error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "May in bounds");
                break;
            case 6:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 31) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Jun out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Jun error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Jun in bounds");
                break;
            case 7:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Jul out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Jul error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Jul in bounds");
                break;
            case 8:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Aug out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Aug error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Aug in bounds");
                break;
            case 9:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 31) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Sep out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Sep error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Sep in bounds");
                break;
            case 10:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Oct out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Oct error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Oct in bounds");
                break;
            case 11:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 31) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Nov out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Nov error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Nov in bounds");
                break;
            case 12:
                try {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) > 0) && (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) < 32) != true) {
                        Log.i(E, "Dec out of bounds");
                        return sArray;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.i(E, "Dec error");
                    return sArray;
                }
                Log.i(E, "Dec in bounds");
                break;

        }

    try {
        if(s.substring(5,6).equals("/") != true) {
            Log.i(E, "second slash out of bounds");
            return sArray;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Log.i(E, "second slash error");
        return sArray;
    }
    Log.i(E, "second slash in bounds");

    try {
        if((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6)) < 1700 && Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6)) < 2600) == true) {
            Log.i(E, "century out of bounds");
            return sArray;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Log.i(E, "century error");
        return sArray;
    }
        sArray[1] = "PASS";
        return sArray;
}

}
package dayOfWeekApp;

public class GuassAlgorithm {


public static String getDate(String s){ //method declaration

    if(s == "error"){
        return "error";
    }

    String dayOfWeek = "some day"; //String declared with variable to test if anything is changing

    int centuryInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 8));
    int decadeAndYearInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 10));
    int monthInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2));
    int dayInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5));

    Object monthName[][] = {{3, "March"}, {4, "April"}, {5, "May"}, {6, "June"}, {7, "July"}, {8, "August"}, {9, "September"}, {10, "October"}, {11, "November"}, {12, "December"}, {13, "January"}, {14, "February"}};

    switch (monthInt){
    case 1: monthInt = 12; //jan
        break;
    case 2: monthInt = 13; //feb
        break;
    case 3: monthInt = 0; //mar
        break;
    case 4: monthInt = 1; //apr
        break;
    case 5: monthInt = 2; //may
        break;
    case 6: monthInt = 3; //jun
        break;
    case 7: monthInt = 4; //jul
        break;
    case 8: monthInt = 5; //aug
        break;
    case 9: monthInt = 6; //sep
        break;
    case 10: monthInt = 7; //oct
        break;
    case 11: monthInt = 8; //nov
        break;
    case 12: monthInt = 9; //dec
        break;
    }
```

This is the algorithm developed by Charles Gauss to calculate the day of the week.
Why I number the months and then immediately run it as m+1 then never use it again is beyond me. That's the algorithm.

```
        int h = (dayInt + (26*(monthInt+1)/10) + decadeAndYearInt + (decadeAndYearInt/4) + (centuryInt/4) + (5*centuryInt)) % 7;

        String weekDays[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        dayOfWeek = weekDays[h];

            return dayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

**Bonus points if you can see why my editText is acting like it losses focus after the happyBirthday image is presented.

Comment: `When I call happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) nothing happens` what not happening ?

Comment: What I meant to say is that the imageView does not change color or change any of its other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView happybirthdayimage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
    final TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    final EditText editTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    happybirthdayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Could also be caused by demensions of the imageView in the XML file. I tried it and it wouldn't show up until  I added padding to the image view.

Comment: The imageView was 0px wide, happybirthdayimage forced it to expand to fit it. So, when it appeared that the happybirthdayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) was clearing the image, it was in fact, letting the view collapse back to 0px wide.

Thank you :)

Comment: sweet! I just joined and needed 10 rep points to post an image with my question! Glad I could help!